# Alter <ItemGroup> Content Sequence

Tags: msbuild

I have a primary build file that is managed through source control.  It contains a project `<Import>` that adds a project that contains settings unique to the local environment.  I want to add a temporary project to my copy of the local project file, so I have the following.

Primary Build File:

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="LocalOptions.xml" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <CatalogProject Include="$(SolutionRoot)\MainProject\MainProject.vbproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Local Project File:

```
<Project>

  <ItemGroup>
    <CatalogProject Include="$(SolutionRoot)\LocalProject\LocalProject.vbproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

My problem is that my temporary project depends on one of the projects referenced in the primary build file.  But, my temporary file appears before the dependent file in the `<ItemGroup>` list.

How can I alter the local project file so that my project file is the last file in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you import `LocalOptions.xml` at the end of the file after `CatalogProject` declaration? It'll solve your problem.

Comment: True, this will solve the problem.  Unfortunately, LocalOptions.xml has a role to set properties that are used by the targets in the Primary Build file.  But, your suggestion made me think that I can add another file that is imported at the end of the Primary Build file.  Thanks.